# SRV record to serve a webpage at a specific IP/Port

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, port, hosting

I have a website "mydomain.ca"

And I have a web management front end hosted at different IP, port 1234

I'm trying to get a SRV record to work so that whenever I go to subsite.mydomain.ca it will serve up the web management front end.

---

I've already got a DNS record that points subsite.mydomain.ca to my 192.192.192.192:22200 web management page, which I can access at subsite.mydomain.ca:1234

Ideally, I'm simply looking to have the port stripped off the URL.

Here is the SRV record I'm trying:

```
_hostname._tcp.mydomain.ca. SRV 0 0 1234 subsite.mydomain.ca.   Automatic
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Am I supposed to be using a specific service name instead of hostname?

Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't make sense. You said it's a web site. What do you think is going to use the SRV record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how the SRV records work.

In order to accomplish this you should configure your webserver to forward subsite.mydomain.ca to subsite.mydomain.ca:1234 or configure it to work as a proxy relaying all the traffic from subsite.mydomain.ca to subsite.mydomain.ca:1234 without the user knowing.

A third alternative would be to use a simple PHP/ASP/Perl/Python/etc script that just redirects the user.

I prefer the proxy :)

simple nginx proxy:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name subsite.mydomain.ca;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://subsite.mydomain.ca:1234;
        }
}
```

simple apache proxy: (uses 'mod_proxy'):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName subsite.mydomain.ca
        LogLevel info ssl:warn
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ProxyPass "/"  "http://subsite.mydomain.ca:1234/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Each of these methods would allow me to access the url without the port number?

Comment: Proxy yes. Redirect yes, but the url that is finally displayed in a browser shows a port.